# Is the message "Data cannot be recovered." when reformatting misleading to users?

Tags: interaction-design, android, deletion, warnings

My Android phone gives the following message when I try to format a volume (SD card or USB OTG.)

> Formatting SD card will delete all data. Data cannot be recovered. Continue?

Now, this message is obviously (correctly) trying to warn the user that if they have any data they care about on the SD card, they should back it up before formatting.

However, the statement "data cannot be recovered" is factually incorrect. In fact, much of the data can usually be recovered with tools such as Photorec, Recuva and Disk Drill.

Why does this matter to the user? Well, someone may, for example, be thinking of passing on a storage medium to someone else, and want to make sure none of their naughty photos or business secrets will be retrievable by that person. A tech illiterate person who knows little or nothing about how digital data storage works, could easily take this message literally as an assurance that their data is securely deleted.

How should the message be written to warn the user about data loss while also emphasizing that formatting the volume is not a secure way to shred data?

Every OS I have ever used has warned me when formatting volumes or deleting files. But I cannot recall a single one ever pointing out that it's not *really* a secure way to erase the data. Why is this?

Edit (After most answers): In case anyone is curious, it's a Samsung Galaxy S3 (I9305) running stock Android 4.4.4. Here's what the process looks like:

[image]

Some of the language aspects of this question are now [posted on English SE.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326387/definitions-of-the-word-delete-vs-public-understanding-of-the-word)

Comment: They also might want to be more clear about what "all data" means: "Formatting the SD card will delete all the data on it. ..." (Not all data on my device.)

Comment: @KenMohnkern True, one might assume users are familiar enough with these devices to know that distinction but assuming anything for all users is dangerous.

Comment: People who are concerned about security don't need to be told - they know what the score is.  The average user cares about losing their files.  The message should convey to them that the *expectation* of recovering their files goes to zero following this operation.  It doesn't need to convey that the *expectation* of the data being irrecoverably eliminated is also non-zero.  It should, however, not suggest that the data is expected to be irrecoverably eliminated unless the operation is designed specifically to do so.

Comment: @J... There are probably some people who do care about their private photos, but still need to be told. Example: http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/are-your-selfies-safe-researchers-recover-100s-of-nude-photos-from-second-hand-smartphones-9599373.html

Comment: For the average user one should assume the data cannot be recovered; Recuva and its ilk can be hard to use for non-tech-savvy people to use and they are virtually never 100% accurate/able to recover all data, so it's better to assume you can't

Comment: In addition to @MilkeyMouse I'd note that this phrase could also be read as "data cannot be recovered trivially" which would make the statement factually correct. The problem about providing the statement in this way is that you generate the expectation that the software of the device will also let you recover the data you just deleted, which is not the case.

Comment: @MilkeyMouse Yes, surely a warning has to be made. The question is how to warn the user without risking leading the user to believe that it's a secure erase.

Comment: @Cronax It seems that if we're gonna write a technically accurate, well communicated warning here, it needs to be wordy and complicated, unfortunately. Unless there's a genius wordsmith around.

Comment: @Fiksdal To me it feels like the technical inaccuracy is a small loss compared to the ease of understanding of the current version. To begin with, data recovery tools were developed specifically to recover data that would otherwise be irrecoverable. If such "edge cases" are taken into account then almost any error- or warning message will need to become a novel if it is to be factually and technically correct. This defeats the purpose of a short question that the user will actually *read* before making a mistake they cannot easily undo.

Comment: @Cronax Yes. It seems to be difficult to point out data-recovery possibility without confusing the user regarding the seriousness of the action.

Comment: To be pedantic, *some* operating systems do actually securely erase the data (or have ways to do so). For example, SSD offers a TRIM command that will securely delete the data, and on Android devices, you can choose to encrypt the SD card before you format it, making the information irrecoverable by "normal" programs like Recuva and so on (because all they will see is random bits of meaningless data). While I agree that it's misleading to say "irrecoverable" on most devices, consumers are increasingly given the option to make sure data *really is* irrecoverable.

Comment: On my Cyanogenmod nightly Android 5.1.1 build, the title is: "Erase SD card"; the explanatory text is: "Erase the SD card? You will lose **all** data on the card!" and the button reads "ERASE SD CARD".

Comment: @MichaelHampton That is certainly a bit better than the example in OP.

Comment: While we're on the topic, Google publish their own [writing guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/writing.html#writing-language) and [writing guidelines for accessibility](https://www.google.com/design/spec/usability/accessibility.html#accessibility-writing).

Comment: @MichaelHampton I see. Is this warning message written by Android devs or Samsung?

Comment: The particular message I quoted is pure Android straight from Google. It's also more recent than the one you've asked about, though. The guidelines have changed over time, and some things that were done in the past are no longer recommended.

Comment: @MichaelHampton What about the one I asked about? Was it written by Samsung or Google?

Comment: I can't be sure. I don't have either a 4.4.4 device or a Samsung device to hand.

Comment: @MichaelHampton OK.

Comment: Not in the question, but I would replace the “Continue” button with some variation of “Erase” or “Format”.

Comment: This reminds me of a sign in a stairwell in a building where I used to work. "NOT A STORAGE AREA. CONTENTS WILL BE REMOVED".  And so of course that's where people started putting broken office furniture, rather than calling facilities. The sign said that removal was guaranteed, right?  Of course that area quickly became full of broken furniture that was removed whenever the fire marshal pointed out that an escape route was full of broken furniture.  Point being: in both this case and your case, the second sentence can simply be removed.

Comment: @EricLippert Yeah, this is a nice example.

Comment: This is not a stock Android device.This is Samsung touchwiz

Comment: @SuiciDoga I'm talking about the stock Samsung firmware as opposed to a custom ROM.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I see no problem with the message that other suggestions completely solve.

> Formatting SD card will delete all data. Data cannot be recovered. Continue?

Data cannot be recovered gives a very good sense of urgency, and speaks well to the target audience who at this juncture needs to know the likely worst case scenario. Even though the data can be recovered, it is beyond most people's knowledge. Additionally, it may be true! Although the data can be recovered by special software or hardware, depending on the next actions the data needed to recover the data might make the data unrecoverable (a 4GB drive 100% full of 1 movie, once formatted and a couple songs written to it, the odds of recovering the video are slim).

As @DasBeasto recommended:

> This action cannot be undone.

I'd venture the subtle difference is too slim, possibly regional or related to age to merit this change alone. Although a study would be interesting.

Instead, my suggestion is to add a Chrome Incognito like "Success" message at the end of the operation. Something that says something like:

> "Format Successful!
>
> "Did you know, this does not prevent the bad guys and the feds from reading your old data from your SD card? discard old storage securely!
>
> You may now write new Data to your SD card."

Comment: 1+ for the idea of having the second warning after the formatting is done.

Comment: I like the combination of the [DasBeasto's](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/94317/57088) "_Formatting SD card will delete all data. This action cannot be undone. Continue?_" before the event, to emphasize what matters to most people (your data _will_ disappear, and there's no _built-in_ way of reversing that) with the post-event warning that it may still be recoverable.

Comment: @TripeHound Yes!

Comment: I like a combination of this and this one: http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/94408/83604

Comment: I can understand why. From a UX perspective I wouldn't use it however. `"Data will likely be unrecoverable"` asks more questions than it answers... Now the user wonders how likely, or worse assumes the message is unsure of what is happening. A warning should be sure of itself, imo.

Comment: @AustinFrench: What questions would it "ask"?  If the user needs the data to be unrecoverable, some other means of erasure should be used but it's not the job of the format utility to help the user fine one.  If the user may want the data again, it should be obvious that "data is sitting on disk" would be more helpful than "data might possibly be recoverable".

Comment: @AustinFrench: An after-action message like yours could be helpful, but yours seems a bit chummy.  Better might be something like "Information has been erased, and may no longer be read by normal means, but might not be completely destroyed".  A picture of a handwritten page being erased using a pencil eraser might be worth 1,000 words, given that such erasers often erase things well enough to allow paper to be reused, but don't always obscure them completely.

Comment: Agree with supercat. I hate automated messages that try to be my friend. Also, "the feds" is only relevant in _your_ country (and some others) and thus is not "portable" to the rest of the world.

Comment: I agree that the "Did you know..." message is a good addition. One thought based upon this scenario, how about displaying the message *while* it's formatting? Presumably there is some progress bar or spinner during formatting, I wonder if people would be more likely to read the message when they can't do anything else, rather than post-completion where seeing **Success!** is often sufficient to prevent people reading further messages.

Comment: @Chris , brilliant as well! And yes, that message was chummy and irrelevant and regional I will admit. I was just having a hell of a time coming up with something as succinct AND descriptive.

Comment: @AustinFrench +1 Good answer! If it must be noted that these changes are possibly recovered then splitting it into multiple messages like this is the best way, one long message won't get read. I also agree with the idea of doing it during the format, in my experience formatting a card takes quite a few minutes plenty of time to get read.

Comment: The issue with a two-stage approach is that the user might need to do both, because only the second message tells him that the process which he started will not suffice. That's why I like @wintvelt 's idea.

Answer (score 128):

"Recovered" is a poor choice of words here. All that app is trying to do is warn people that the action is not reversible and they can't simply hit cancel or undo and all their files will be returned. A better solution would be:

> Formatting SD card will delete all data. This action cannot be undone. Continue?

This is more direct to the point that you simply can't undo the deletion, it  keeps the sense of urgency but since it doesn't say "recovered" it doesn't give the impression of a full secure wipe to people who have heard the importance of doing so but never been trained to do it.

Comment: Perhaps language should be added/modified, in order to satisfy OP's "...while also emphasizing that formatting the volume is not a secure way to shred data?"

Comment: @Snowman I personally don't think that is necessary. In the way I worded it the user (hopefully) wouldn't even get the idea of shredding it in their mind, so stating that it doesn't do so would be overkill.

Comment: A fair point. I only noticed that the OP asked that it be emphasizes.

Comment: And working in and around IT for 10+ years I have often seen the confusion about what "delete" means to the common user.

Comment: @Snowman That is a valid point I tried to think of a better way to phrase delete but I couldn't without either not relaying what the app is actually doing or without being too verbose and over explaining (spoonfeeding) the information.

Comment: I agree and you got my up-vote, even if I have a "competing" answer. There are always trade-offs and between over- and under-explaining. Probably the truly correct thing to do is make the software do what users expect... but that's off topic here, no?

Comment: @Snowman Yes, this was my intention in OP. I wish there would be a way to bake that in there. My feeling is that most common people understand the word delete to mean "remove so that it's totally gone". I'm sure there's already been a question about this on this SE. Still, +1.

Comment: @Fiksdal perhaps replacing "will delete all data" with "will purge all data" will give a better impression that the data will be gone but without the finality of the term "delete" because you wont really state where it is "purged" to?

Comment: @DasBeasto I had to look up the definition of *purge.* IMO *purge* plays similarly to *delete*, only it's a more mysterious word.

Comment: @Fiksdal true it will be similar but that's because the data *is* deleted. I can't imagine there is a way to imply that data isn't deleted when it is, this just avoids the preconception that it is permanently obliterated that the word "delete" portrays.

Comment: Semantics... maybe this is English Language SE material now :)  I had a problem with putting "delete" into an API that I was writing once. It was a collaborative deal and one of the people programming an app that used the API wanted a "delete" added, and I told him that I would not allow a client to actually delete anything. We argued for a while because we had different concepts of what delete should do. In the end we did it my way, because I was writing the API, but we settled on allowing his app to "retire" information, which made it invisible to him.

Comment: @DasBeasto Yes. Our problem is the twofold meaning of the word *delete* in the minds of common people vs. the strict definition in computing terms. If I was authoring these messages, I'd probably try to be clear. Admittedly the messages would probably end up a bit wordy and confusing.

Comment: What about clear or wipe, not delete?

Comment: @Tim the problem is that there's no short phrase that will explain that the data isn't going to be trivially accessible any longer, but that specialized tools can still recover it. Those tools are also not 100% guaranteed to be successful, which further complicates the issue.

Comment: As a technical user, when I see "delete" my default inference is "the directory entries for these files will be cleared". "Wipe" implies a more thorough deletion of the actual data, and one that (ideally) prevents even forensic recovery is called "secure wipe" or "scrub". But I also know that in solid state media, secure deletion can be much more difficult (due to the write-cycle limitations); a simply-deleted file on an HDD is likely to be overwritten in short order, but on an SSD, normally, all never-used sectors will have to get used once before the first "deleted" sector is overwritten.

Answer (score 15):

Really good question.

I've thought about this inaccuracy (although in a security, not UX context) and had to explain to several colleagues that most "delete" options (yes, even formatting a drive) are not secure and that the data is quite often recoverable.

I have never found it difficult, nor has anyone failed to understand, that the way to think about this is that the operating system will no longer recognize the content and that it is thus available to be overwritten. It may be as simple as wording it along the lines of.

> Formatting SD card will make all current data unavailable to the operating system. Data cannot be recovered without using special software. Continue?

Or I rather like the [FOLDOC](http://foldoc.org/delete) definition for "delete":

> To make a file inaccessible.

"Inaccessible" doesn't mean it's gone, we just can't get to it. Thus:

> After formatting the SD card all data will be inaccessible. Continue?

This does not *emphasize* that the data is not gone, but it does *mean* that. Do we need to include something about potential recovery? That might depend on how security-critical the operation is considered to be.

Maybe not the perfect wording, but my point is that the truth isn't difficult to understand and you've made an excellent point in the fact that the inaccurate wording could actually be a disservice to less savvy users.

#### EDIT

Another, more verbose but perfectly accurate versions courtesy of Mark Stewart (comments below)

> Formatting SD card will make all current data on the *SD card*
>   unavailable to the operating system. Data cannot *generally* be
>   recovered; using special software *may recover some* data. Continue?

Comment: 1+, I like the suggested message also. But can we make it slightly more alarming? Like adding "partly recover" or something? Don't know how to phrase it. (You know, since the OS may immediately overwrite some of the sectors. Also, if it's a fragmented filesystem, I think formatting may overwrite the index, which will lead to many fragmented and/or corrupted files, even if immediately attempting recovery. I actually experienced this recently when a friend of mine accidentally formatted a FAT32 volume.)

Comment: @Fiksdal I didn't consider that. It's a valid concern if we're talking about pushing for a paradigm shift on this type of warning. I feel it is a little out of context to the OP's concern which is about not misleading the user to believe that his data is truly gone and not about warning him that it may only be partially recoverable.

Comment: Haha.. Yeah, we might as well put a whole lecture into the warning :)

Comment: `...cannot be recovered without using special software` - this gives the impression that there should be some expectation that data recovery is possible.  In reality, the probability of data recovery following a format operation is *undefined*.  An appropriate message should not give the user any impression otherwise.  The *expectation* of data recovery should be zero following a format.  The *expectation* of data elimination following a format should also be zero.

Comment: How about `Formatting SD card will make all current data on the *SD card* unavailable to the operating system. Data cannot *generally* be recovered; using special software *may recover some* data. Continue?`

Comment: @J... really, really good points. I'll see about editing the answer a little taking that into account.

Comment: @MarkStewart may I plagiarize, at least in part. It's getting wordy but suits the original question and subsequent concerns well

Comment: @MarkStewart I love this one. I think your should post it as an answer.

Comment: @MarkStewart: Seems a little wordy.  I think "Data will likely be unrecoverable" would suffice.  While some people might take "likely" to mean "over 50% chance", and while the probability of rendering data completely unrecoverable would be less than that, I don't think anyone who would be dissatisfied with a 50% chance of real destruction would be satisfied with anything less than 90%, and the adverb "likely" does not imply anything near that.

Comment: @supercat That's a great suggestion, you can post it as an answer!

Comment: I don't think "inaccessible" will necessarily have the implication that you think it will for non-tech savvy users. "Inaccessible" just means it can't be accessed, it doesn't imply anything about *why* it can't be accessed. I see it as no different to "cannot be recovered" in terms of not making the actual situation clear.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: While I don't think the analogy would be good in a prompt, I'd view reformatting in such a case as analogous to tossing an object made of a robust material from a ship into the ocean.  The object may or may not continue to exist for any particular length of time, and likely would never been seen again, but could potentially pop up unexpectedly.

Comment: OK, how about a brief message, and two buttons:  `Details` and `Shoot myself in the foot`

Comment: `all data will be inaccessible` sounds a lot better than the original.

Comment: `unavailable to the operating system` - what's an *operating system*? Can we remove that jargon?

Comment: Instead of `special software` I'd suggest `specialized tools` as there may exist hardware methods for data recovery also (in fact, hardware methods are oftentimes even better at recovering deleted data than software is).

Answer (score 7):

I know the question is about the text, but in addition to others responses, consider that user don't always read what you have written and can click on a single button as a habit/reflex.

Consider adding 2 buttons with exact same formatting to force them process the information

[image]

Comment: Yes, this. A button's label should be clearly stating what the button does, instead of a simple `Yes`, `No`, `Cancel`, `Continue`. ("No, do nothing" would be even better than "No, cancel"). And a "dangerous" operation should provide a user with an easy way out instead of making them hope tapping the screen somewhere else, or the back menu button, will cancel the operation.

Comment: Along that line, another good practice for a destructive operation is to disable the "yes" button for a few seconds when the prompt first loads. This prevents an accidental double tap, e.g. if the button that opened this screen was positioned near the "yes" button, and also increases the likelihood of the message being read by the user.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest "Data will likely be unrecoverable" as having a clear meaning that is unlikely to materially mislead anyone.  While it is true that the likelihood of data being truly unrecoverable if nothing is done with the cartridge following the format might not be as high as the adverb "likely" would suggest, few if any users will care about the odds in such a way that it would matter.  Someone who discovers they need to recover some files but is unable to do so can't complain if something described as "likely", turned out to be the case; on the flip side, since "likely" is decidedly weaker than "certainly", anyone who wants certain destruction should recognize that "likely" isn't apt to fit their needs, regardless of whether the probability would be 10% or 90%.

Comment: I like this combined with the after-message suggested here: http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/94343/83604

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the UX should go in a completely different direction here. Starting with some (always dangerous) assumptions about context:

- The majority of users landing on this bit of UI are here because they want to re-use the SD card on the same device. They have no intention of removing the SD card, or sharing it with anyone.
- And many of those users actually hate being here: formatting is a necessary evil. They think "Why do I have to do this, I was downloading stuff I care about, and then was rudely interrupted with a "not enough space" message" before I got to this bit.
- For that majority, the purpose of being here is **to quickly empty a medium for reuse of that medium**.
- For them, the current message is not bad. I personally like the "cannot be undone" best, and find the Samsung process in your question needlessly annoying ("you entered your pin to confirm, but are really really sure?"). But in essence, the message is "warning, you are about to do something dangerous"
- Of course, there could be a small minority of users who are actually here NOT because they want to reuse the medium, but for a completely different purpose: **to safely destroy any data on the medium**.

So the challenge is:

- Facilitate the "quickly empty medium" primary purpose.
- Alert about no easy recovery of data to them
- Also warn that data can still be recovered somehow.
- Without confusing the primary purpose.

How about something like:

[image]

Comment: This is actually a better answer than the others. It also highlights one of the main issues: the term "format" is a technical term with no real meaning to end users. (In fact, it has multiple technical meanings, depending on how the formatting is done.) Really, we need to rename this "Clear SD card" or "Renew SD card", with the message "Renew will empty the SD card for reuse by discarding all data. This action cannot be undone. Continue?"  I think you've hit upon the heart of the matter.

Comment: Well, personally, I only needed "format" when I wanted to pass the card (or USB stick) to somebody else, so I think the first assumption is not quite correct. Anyway, the design proposed cares for both.

Answer (score 2):

I think the message is fine. It's not about giving people all the information, or even all the options.

> Formatting SD card will delete all data on this specific card Serial Number XXXXXXXXX. Data cannot be easily recovered, but may be recovered using some tools with an unknown degree of success depending on how many sectors of this device are altered after formatting. Recovery may or may not be possible. Other external factors apply. Samsung and Google make no clams that data will or will not be recoverable. Continue?

That's a bit much. So instead, think about the action and the consequence to the most likely user.

> If you smash yes your data be gone!

Well, ok that doesn't sound "professional".

The point is that it doesn't matter that the data is potentially recoverable. It's not recoverable using the tools built in to the OS/Phone. A normal user will not be able to recover the data. Any user smart enough to recover the data will know so at the time of the message. As for sharing cards, that's not the primary audience. The primary audience is new cards or fixing old cards.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not so much about what the OS is doing, as clarifying the assumptions that naive users are making about what the OS is doing. How about ...

> Formatting this card will allow it to be used for new data storage. Assume you will not be able to recover your old data. Assume that any bad guy that gets this card **will** be able to recover your old data.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

> Formatting SD card will erase existing data. Continue with erasure?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't add

> Data cannot be recovered

I would add it only in the case of a full erase (in case you have the option available to your users).

An other issue is with

> Continue ?

I believe you than give "Yes" and "No" as choices to your users ? If you do, it probably isn't the best practice as it forces the user to read the whole message to know ether they should click on 'yes' or 'no'. Instead, you should give options such as "Delete" and "Cancel".
(By the way, depending on the OS it will be running on, you should carefully choose the place of the buttons.

Comment: Regarding button placement, this seems to be a clear case for a very big easy-target "Cancel" button, and a very small bright red "Delete" button.

Comment: @Wildcard In actual fact, here's what it looks like on my phone. It's a Samsung I9305. There's not even a "cancel" button. One has to use the *back* or *home* button.   http://i.stack.imgur.com/nggsS.png
  http://i.stack.imgur.com/SmDpp.png
  http://i.stack.imgur.com/t48iU.png

Answer (score 1):

Add another paragraph after the warning that your data may not be retrievable:

Warning:  formatting is not an authorized method of destroying classified or confidential data such as old passwords, naughty photos, or your credit card number.

(What would I recommend?  (a) contact a reputable data destruction service, (b) read the government standards for data destruction and implement one of the methods, (c) heat the media to at least 5700 °C, which is higher than the boiling point of Tungsten, which has the highest known boiling point of any element, or (d) detonate a nuclear weapon within 1 meter of it.  But I wouldn't put any of this paragraph in the warning message.)

Comment: Some people say you have to detonate 3 consecutive nukes before you can be sure your data is wiped.

Answer (score 0):

I like the way Ubuntu has solved this problem. Admittedly it's a bit wordy, and may confuse total tech illiterates a little bit. But it's very technically accurate, and I find it a good solution. This screenshot is from the native disk management tool in 16.04.

[image]